# Why cannot I catch the exception thrown in nested catch clause using 'outer' catch?

Tags: java, exception, nested, try-catch

In the example below, you can see that the IOException (named FOURTH) exception cannot be caught using the outer catch clause. Why is that?
I know exceptions can be caught if its thrown in a nested try block, using outer catch.
If you change the b static variable value to false then you can see this.

But why cant we catch the exception thrown in a nested catch clause using an outer catch?

```
import java.io.*;

public class Exceptions {

    static boolean b = true;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        try {
            exceptions(b);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e  + " is handled by main().");
        }       
    }

    static void exceptions(boolean b) throws Exception{
        try{
            if(b) throw new FileNotFoundException("FIRST");
            try{
                throw new IOException("SECOND");
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException e){
                System.out.println("This will never been printed out.");
            }
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            System.out.println(e + " is handled by exceptions().");
            try{
                throw new FileNotFoundException("THIRD");        
            }
            catch(FileNotFoundException fe){            
                System.out.println(fe + " is handled by exceptions() - nested.");
            }
            try{
                throw new IOException("FOURTH");
            }
            finally{}
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e + " is handled by exceptions().");
        }
    }
}
```

The output if b = true :

**java.io.FileNotFoundException: FIRST is handled by exceptions(). java.io.FileNotFoundException: THIRD is handled by exceptions() - nested. java.io.IOException: FOURTH is handled by main().**

The output if b = false:

**java.io.IOException: SECOND is handled by exceptions().**

Comment: What happens if you remove `finally{}` after the "FOURTH" exception?

Comment: It does. Find the last `try/catch` statement.

Comment: You're not throwing it from the `try` block, you are throwing it from the `catch` block.

Comment: What happens when you run this, is the exception completely uncaught?

Comment: @Chthonic Project if you remove finally{} then it wont compile

Comment: @Keppil yes, on purpose I throw it in the catch block

Comment: @Chris the one in exceptions() of course :)

Comment: Why do you throw them inside the try block and why do you expect your throw to propagate outside your try block? How do you expect it t distinguish between your own exception (that you want to propagate) and any other exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> But why cant we catch the exception thrown in a nested catch clause using an outer catch?

You can.  The problem is that your last `catch(Exception e)` is at the **same** level of nesting which is why it doesn't catch an exception thrown in a previous catch block.

Try nesting your try/catch blocks like this

```
static void exceptions(boolean b) {
    try {
        try {
            if (b) throw new FileNotFoundException("FIRST");
            try {
                throw new IOException("SECOND");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                System.out.println("This will never been printed out.");
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e + " is handled by exceptions().");
            try {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("THIRD");
            } catch (FileNotFoundException fe) {
                System.out.println(fe + " is handled by exceptions() - nested.");
            }
            // will be caught by the nested try/catch at the end.
            throw new IOException("FOURTH");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e + " is handled by exceptions().");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Chris in that case there isn't a problem AFAICS.

Comment: thanks for your example, Its great. However, I know we can catch exceptions thrown in nested try block using outer catch. This is what happens with my exception SECOND when b = false. My question is why cant we do the same thing when b = true? (IOexception FOURTH thrown in a nested catch cannot be caught in an outer catch?) Why you guys saying that my catch(Exception e) clause is on the same level than the thrown IOException FOURTH (which is clearly inside another try block) ?? thanks

Comment: @LazLondon  The `try` for `catch(FNFE` is the **same** as for `catch(Exception`  In my example, there is a different `try { try {`

Comment: Yes, i know this Peter, my catch(FNFE) and catch(Exception) are on the same level..however my FOURTH exception is 1 level deeper...(inside another try block) sorry if i am annoying, just trying to understand why it cannot be caught using my code snippet.

Comment: @LazLondon You FOURTH is outside the `try { something } catch` area. It is not in the `something` it is after it and not caught again.  Say you had `try { throw new Exception(); } catch(Exception e) { throw e; }` You wouldn't want `throw e` to be caught by the `try` as it would produce an infinite loop.  So anything thrown by a catch block is not in the scope caught by the `try`

Comment: I have something like this: `try { throw FNFE } catch(FNFE e){ try {throw IOE} finally{}} catch(Exception e)` and IOE is not caught...

Comment: @LazLondon Correct, nor should it.  The `catch(Exception e)` is for the first `try { something }` block, it doesn't wrap any of the catch blocks after it because it is at the same level so it won't try/catch anything thrown in a catch block.

Answer (score 4):

Your structure is some thing like this

```
try {
 //operation
}
catch (Exce 1){ //catch 1
   // throw IO
}
catch(Exce 2){ //catch 2
   // print error
}
```

Here catch1 and catch2 are at same level, and the exception thrown from catch1 will not reach catch2.

Hence Your IOE will be thrown  back to the caller . If you want to handle the exception with in the method, then follow some thing below

```
try{

    try {
     //operation
    }
    catch (Exce 1){ //catch 1
       // throw IO
    }
    catch(Exce 2){ //catch 2
       // print error
    }

}
catch(Exce 3) {
  // your IO will be caught here 
}
```

Comment: First of all, thanks for the example. But as I stated before, I know we can catch exceptions thrown in nested try block using outer catch. This is what happens with my exception SECOND when b = false. My question is why cant we do the same thing when b = true? (IOexception FOURTH thrown in a nested catch cannot be caught in an outer catch?) Why you guys saying that it my `catch(Exception e)` clause is on the same level than the thrown IOException FOURTH (this is clearly inside another try block) ?? thanks